# jQuery - combining functions

Tags: jquery

One that's been bugging me for a while. How would I combine these three sets of code together?

```
$(".fly-out-menu").toggle(
      function () {
        $('#page').animate({left: 250}, 'fast'); },
      function () {
        $('#page').animate({left: 0}, 'fast'); }
);
$(".fly-out-menu").toggle(
      function () {
        $('.sticky-container').animate({left: 250}, 'fast'); },
      function () {
        $('.sticky-container').animate({left: 0}, 'fast'); }
);
$(".fly-out-menu").toggle(
      function () {
        $('body').css('position','fixed') },
      function () {
        $('body').css('position','static') }
);
```

Thanks,
R

Comment: `toggle` method is deprecated, there is no rule that prevents you from wrting more-than-one-line functions.

Comment: Doesn't say it's deprecated... http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: You are using this toggle http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Comment: Is there an alternative?

Comment: In jQuery API, no, but you can create something like a flag easily.

Comment: See the edit I just made. (Thank you @undefined for bringing this up)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like that?

```
$(".fly-out-menu").toggle(
    function(){
        $('#page, .sticky-container').animate({left: 250}, 'fast');
        $('body').css('position','fixed');
    },
    function(){
        $('#page, .sticky-container').animate({left: 0}, 'fast');
        $('body').css('position','static');
    }
);
```

As pointed out by @undefined, this event is now deprecated.
One way of handling this yourself would be:

```
$(".fly-out-menu").on("click", function(){
    var t = $(this);
    if(!t.data("alreadyclicked")){
        t.data("alreadyclicked", true);
        $('#page, .sticky-container').animate({left: 250}, 'fast');
        $('body').css('position','fixed');
    } else {
        t.data("alreadyclicked", false);
        $('#page, .sticky-container').animate({left: 0}, 'fast');
        $('body').css('position','static');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for all your help. Seems odd that they would deprecate this, but hey ho.

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this?

```
$(".fly-out-menu").toggle(
function () {
    $('#page').animate({left: 250}, 'fast'); 
    $('.sticky-container').animate({left: 250}, 'fast');
    $('body').css('position','fixed');
},
function () {
    $('#page').animate({left: 0}, 'fast');
    $('.sticky-container').animate({left: 0}, 'fast');
    $('body').css('position','static');
}
);
```

Or like this:

```
$(".fly-out-menu").toggle(
function () {
    $('#page, .sticky-container').animate({left: 250}, 'fast');
    $('body').css('position','fixed');
},
function () {
    $('#page, .sticky-container').animate({left: 0}, 'fast');
    $('body').css('position','static');
}
);
```